# Given a very large text file filled with integers,how to sort it?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a very large text file (too large Too fit in main memeory at once) containing integers. I need an algorithic strategy to sort it? If I plan to actually do it (using some strategy on the lines of Merge Sort), will it fail or the Operating System can take care of it? 
P.S. I don't need codes of sorting algorithms.

Comment: External sorting has been around almost as long as computers themselves.  Write the program correctly and it will work. Merge sort of some variation is an entirely suitable starting point.

Comment: If you have an OS, the second step should be consulting its documentation. (The first one whould be nailing down details: range of the integers, encoding, separation, count ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. split the file in chunks of size that you can handle.
2. sort all these chunks.
3. open two of these sorted chunks

   1. create an output file
   2. read in one line/value from each file
   3. determine the smaller value.
   4. write the smaller value to the new file
   5. read a new value from the file that contained the smaller value
   6. if one file reaches EOF

      1. copy the left content of the other to the output file
      2. close the output
      3. delete both chunk files
      4. if more than one file remains (including your outputs) goto 3

example:

```
unsorted file:
168971321965798321487954321687987321654654687987651316879 
-> split
16897132 19657983 214879543 21687987 321654654 6879876 51316879
-> sort
11236789 13567899 123445789 12677889 123445566 6677889 11356789
^        ^        -> 1
 ^       ^            1
  ^      ^             1
  ^       ^             2 
   ^      ^              3
    ^     ^               3
    ^      ^               5
    ^       ^               6
     ^      ^                6
     ^       ^                7
      ^      ^                 7
      ^       ^                 8
       ^      ^                  8
       ^       ^                  9
        eof    ^                   99
-> merge 2 of them
1112335667788999 11223445677788899 1234455666677889 11356789
->
111112223334455666777778888899999 111233445556666677788899
->
111111112222333334444555556666666677777777888888889999999
```

As user2040251 stated this is not the optimal way, since numbers have to be read multiple time. A faster approach can be to open all the chunks parallel and compare select the minium value since the files are read only one time.

Comment: Using k-way merge after sorting each chunk can be more efficient. With you approach, each number is read about `log(number_of_chunks) base 2` times, but it is possible to achieve `log(number of chunks) base (RAM_AVAILABLE / DISK_BLOCK_SIZE)` times. For example, if you have 32 chunks, your approach requires reading each number 5 times after sorting the chunks, but k-way merge requires only 1 pass.

Comment: @user2040251 yes i first thought about it but I decided to use only 2 files because it seemed to be a more natural approach in terms of command line tooling but may be it would also ok to pass a number of files. I added a note about this. it is faster because the file read is only done once. the numbers itself are touched equally often since you need find the minimum of all values you read in.

Comment: There's also the possibility of splitting the source into _ranges_ rather than chunks, which is more work to handle cases where ranges are not roughly the same size, but allows you to bypass the merge step.

Comment: Also, if the total range of the values is small enough compared to the count of the values, an O(1) counting sort becomes viable.  I had the assignment to sort a billion 32bit integers, I made an array of 2^32 nibbles for counts of 0-14, and then had a hash of the few values that had 15+.

Answer (score 0):

Mooing Duck inspired me with his comment to another solution:

use some map-like structure that maps `value`->`count` in e.g. c++ `std::map<YourDataToSort, uint32_t>` or some kind ob balanced binary tree.

1. open your input file
2. read it line/element wise

   1. if element is allready in the list:

      1. increase the count
      2. if the count was at its maximum value and cannot be increased follow the procedure described below (at 2.2.2.)
   2. else check the memory that the map uses (`keyCount * sizeof(key) * sizeof(counter) + someOverhead*keyCount`) - you may simply set some key limit determined by this rough guess with enough tolerance:

      1. if limit is not exeeded :

         - add an new an entry with count 1
      2. else

         - create an output file
         - sort the keys of the mapping structure (if they are not sorted by implementation)
         - write the each key value `count` times to the output
         - close file
         - clear mapping structure
         - continue with 2.

This algorithm may produce less files (obviously depends on your data) than my other answer. Since disk performance often is the bottleneck the mapping structure handling will be acceptable since it saves some expensive file read-merge-write cycles. If multiple files are generated merge them with the algorithm described in the other answer.

This approach has a higher memory requirement compared to using a simple lookup, there the number itself is the index but it can handle negative numbers, very large value ranges and is not even limited to integer as data. Only requirement is, that the mapping of data->count is unique does not create collision.